# Moving files to server jsp

Tags: file, jsp, server, move

How can i move file to hosting?
I use this code but it doesn't work.

```
File uploads = new File("/Users/Aurimo/Desktop/");
File file = new File(request.getParameter("dataFile"));
    file.renameTo(uploads);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet) - A simple *jsp upload* search inside SO immediately leads there ...

Answer (score 0):

For creating jsp page for upload purpose, You create database, folder in file system, display upload form, then display result. These below links will be helpful for you:

http://www.codejava.net/coding/upload-files-to-database-servlet-jsp-mysql
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_file_uploading.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
use multipart form 

and server side use following code.

for(FileItem item : multiparts){
    if(!item.isFormField()){
        String name = new File(item.getName()).getName();
        item.write( new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + name));
        request.setAttribute("photoname", name);
    }else{
        // here get value of other parameter which is not file type
        System.out.println(item.getFieldName()+" = "+item.getString());
    }
}
```

Comment: help me declare variables item and multiparts

Comment: pl check below answer

Answer (score 0):

```
FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
for (FileItem item : items) {
    if (item.isFormField()) {  //als het een veld is dan dit, anders File uploaden
        String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
        String fieldvalue = item.getString();
        switch (fieldname) {
            case "logicalName":
                LogicalName = fieldvalue;
                break;
            //other case statements...
        }
    } else {
        //here you only have to process the file
        File file;
        int maxFileSize = 500000 * 1024;//your comments...
        int maxMemSize = 5000 * 1024;//your comments...
        //this must be a constant or a servlet init param, do not hard code it
        String filePath = "C:\\uploads\\";
        String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(item.getName());
        factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);
        //didn't you have a filePath variable?
        factory.setRepository(new File("c:\\temp"));
        upload.setSizeMax(maxFileSize);
        try {
            String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
            boolean isInMemory = fi.isInMemory();
            long sizeInBytes = fi.getSize();
            file = new File(filePath, fileName);
            item.write(file);
            //code to save your file location in db...
            //note: this MUST BE in a business logic method, not directly written in your servlet
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            int uploader = (Integer) session.getAttribute("UserId");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //very BAD idea
            //use a logger instead like log4j or sfl4j
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```